# What are the conventions for naming variables in python?

Tags: python

New to coding, trying to work through conventional arrangements. I've seen various naming styles - long and short words, some use Caps for first letter and others not, most use underscore between variable name_words_like_so.

Any conventions for python variable naming I should be aware of for best practices purposes?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a good start. In fact, programs such as pylint can scan a document for conformance and some projects require PEP 8 conformance for code. Lots of code is written using a Windows style (e.g., `myVar`) but PEP 8 (`my_var`) is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out this official Python guide on style conventions: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). If you are interested in [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) in particular, they got such a section. There are several styles of naming available, some preferred more than others. One of the most common ones seems to be `lower_case_with_underscores`. You will encounter this one the most.